# Object usage and its corresponding relative pronoun

Tags: sentence-construction

1. We remain who we are
2. We remain whom we are

Which of the above sentences is correct?

Comment: We remain *who* we are.

Comment: There is no object in either clause: *who we are* is a predicate complement of *remain*, and *who* stands for the predicate complement of *are*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no object in either clause: *who we are* is a predicate complement of *remain*, and *who* stands for the predicate complement of *are*.  - StoneyB

So: *We remain who we are*. – Robusto